# ubuntu mysql not starting

Tags: mysql, apache, ubuntu, lampp

I am using LAMPP on ubuntu 16.04.1 it suddenly stoped working. when I tried restarting lampp it started successfully with the following message

```
Restarting XAMPP for Linux 5.6.28-1...
XAMPP: Stopping Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Stopping MySQL...not running.
XAMPP: Stopping ProFTPD...ok.
XAMPP: Starting Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.
```

but when I check the status it says

```
Version: XAMPP for Linux 5.6.28-1
Apache is running.
MySQL is not running.
ProFTPD is running.
```

I have absolutely no idea why this happening. can any one please help

Comment: Check your log for the errors and post them 
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-linux-mysql-error-log/

Comment: I have no log files generated in that location my apache directory is /opt/lampp/logs

Comment: Check for any errors in your logs location then or edit my.cnf file and manually add an error log for the mysql service then try to start it again and see what's the error

Comment: the error is solved. Apache was not able to detect log file that's why it was not starting. I deleted the file and it started it worked.

Comment: Can you please tell me which log file did you delete exactly?

Comment: I deleted tc.log file.

Comment: @TusharChevulkar where is the file?